# JavaScript-How to show/hide tr textarea by clicking image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three images which called "down.png" and three dropDownTextAreas. I want show/hide textarea separately every time when I click image.

For example, if click first image, first textarea show up, click second image, second textarea show up, etc.

But my problem is every time when I click one of images, all textareas are show up.

Thanks so much!

```
<script>
     function showHide(){
       var textArea = document.getElementsByClassName("dropDownTextArea");
         for(var i=0; i<textArea.length; i++){
       if(textArea[i].style.display == "none"){
         textArea[i].style.display="table-row";
       }else{
         textArea[i].style.display="none";
       }
    }
 }
</script>

<style>
.dropDownTextArea{
  display: none;
}
</style>

<table id="myTable" >
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>STUDENT</th>
            <th>ADVISOR</th>
            <th>AWARD<br/>STATUS</th>
            <th>SEMESTER</th>
            <th>TYPE</th>
            <th>BUDGET<br />#</th>
            <th>PERCENTAGE</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" /><br /><br />
                <img src="down.png" width="25px" onclick="showHide()"/>
            </td>
            <td>Student 1</td>
            <td>Teacher 1</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>Fall</td>
            <td>TA</td>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dropDownTextArea"><td id="myDropDown" colspan="8">
            Advisor:<br /><br />
            Award Details<br />
            Summer 1-2014(TA)<br />
            Budget Number: <img src="pencil.png"><br />
            Tuition Number: <img src="pencil.png"><br />
            Comments:<br /><br /><br />
            Award Status:<br /><br /><br />
        </td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" /><br /><br />
                <img src="down.png" width="25px" onclick="showHide()"/>
            </td>
            <td>Student 2</td>
            <td>Teacher 2</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>Fall</td>
            <td>TA</td>
            <td>23456</td>
            <td>100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dropDownTextArea"><td id="myDropDown" colspan="8">
            Advisor:<br /><br />
            Award Details<br />
            Summer 1-2014(TA)<br />
            Budget Number: <img src="pencil.png" > <br />
            Tuition Number: <img src="pencil.png" ><br />
            Comments:<br /><br /><br />
            Award Status:<br /><br /><br />
        </td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" "/><br /><br />
                <img src="down.png" width="25px" onclick="showHide()"/>
            </td>
            <td>Student 3</td>
            <td>Teacher 3</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>Fall</td>
            <td>TA</td>
            <td>34567</td>
            <td>100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dropDownTextArea" "><td id="myDropDown" colspan="8">
            Advisor:<br /><br />
            Award Details<br />
            Summer 1-2014(TA)<br />
            Budget Number: <img src="pencil.png"><br />
            Tuition Number: <img src="pencil.png"><br />
            Comments:<br /><br /><br />
            Award Status:<br /><br /><br />
        </td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Where are these famous textareas ?

Comment: It's <tr class="dropDownTextArea">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to bind each element `<img>`  as `onclick="showHide(this)"` to the function `showHide(obj)`

[Properties and Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) of DOM Element Object

So your function will be

```
  function showHide(obj) {
   var textArea = document.getElementsByClassName("dropDownTextArea");
   for (var i = 0; i < textArea.length; i++) {
     if (textArea[i].previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.children[3] == obj) {
       if (textArea[i].style.display == "table-row") {
         textArea[i].style.display = "none";
       } else {
         textArea[i].style.display = "table-row"
       }
     } else {
       textArea[i].style.display = "none";
     }


   }
 }
```

[Fiddle Link for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/dh7pchy4/2/)

Comment: Thanks, it did work! But it didn't hide anymore when I click it agin.

Comment: you want to hide it again on click

Comment: If answer is accepted see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) how to mark as accepted

Answer (score 0):

The reason that all of them are showing is because you're selecting all of them in your javascript. This line `var textArea = document.getElementsByClassName("dropDownTextArea");` selects all elements with that class, and you then go on to show them all.

You need to give each dropdown textarea a separate `id` or `class` so that you can select them individually. Below is a potential approach you could take.

```
<script>
  function showHide(dropdown){
    var textArea = document.getElementById(dropdown)
    if(textArea[i].style.display == "none"){
      textArea[i].style.display="table-row";
    }else{
      textArea[i].style.display="none";
    }
 }
</script>

<style>
.dropDownTextArea{
  display: none;
}
</style>

<table id="myTable" >
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>STUDENT</th>
            <th>ADVISOR</th>
            <th>AWARD<br/>STATUS</th>
            <th>SEMESTER</th>
            <th>TYPE</th>
            <th>BUDGET<br />#</th>
            <th>PERCENTAGE</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" /><br /><br />
                <img src="down.png" width="25px" onclick="showHide('dropdown_one')"/>
            </td>
            <td>Student 1</td>
            <td>Teacher 1</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>Fall</td>
            <td>TA</td>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dropDownTextArea" id="dropdown_one"><td id="myDropDown" colspan="8">
            Advisor:<br /><br />
            Award Details<br />
            Summer 1-2014(TA)<br />
            Budget Number: <img src="pencil.png"><br />
            Tuition Number: <img src="pencil.png"><br />
            Comments:<br /><br /><br />
            Award Status:<br /><br /><br />
        </td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" /><br /><br />
                <img src="down.png" width="25px" onclick="showHide('dropdown_two')"/>
            </td>
            <td>Student 2</td>
            <td>Teacher 2</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>Fall</td>
            <td>TA</td>
            <td>23456</td>
            <td>100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dropDownTextArea" id="dropdown_two"><td id="myDropDown" colspan="8">
            Advisor:<br /><br />
            Award Details<br />
            Summer 1-2014(TA)<br />
            Budget Number: <img src="pencil.png" > <br />
            Tuition Number: <img src="pencil.png" ><br />
            Comments:<br /><br /><br />
            Award Status:<br /><br /><br />
        </td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox"/><br /><br />
                <img src="down.png" width="25px" onclick="showHide('dropdown_three')"/>
            </td>
            <td>Student 3</td>
            <td>Teacher 3</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>Fall</td>
            <td>TA</td>
            <td>34567</td>
            <td>100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dropDownTextArea" id="dropdown_three"><td id="myDropDown" colspan="8">
            Advisor:<br /><br />
            Award Details<br />
            Summer 1-2014(TA)<br />
            Budget Number: <img src="pencil.png"><br />
            Tuition Number: <img src="pencil.png"><br />
            Comments:<br /><br /><br />
            Award Status:<br /><br /><br />
        </td></tr>
    </table>
```